# What is the checkmark icon next to my project in PyCharm?

Tags: python, pycharm

One of my PyCharm projects has an extra icon next to its name. I'm referring to what looks like a checkmark between the folder icon and the name of the project. Does anyone know what it is? I can't find anything in the documentation. My other projects don't have this icon -- perhaps I modified some setting in this one that made it appear?

[image]

Comment: Does your project use git?

Comment: I do have Git installed, but as far as I can tell it's not configured in any way for this project. In PyCharm if I go into Settings -> Version Control and have a look at the list of VCS directories configured, there is nothing in the list.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It means the file is bookmarked. You can get rid of it by selecting the file in the project window and pressing CTRL + F11 (or just F11).

Here is more detail (although they do not mention the checkmark...):
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/5.0/managing-bookmarks.html?origin=old_help